# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la ruta de los archivos para subirlos a un servidor FTP con php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ftp

Tengo el siguiente formulario en el cuál quiero subir un archivo a un servidor FTP, con la linea de php mando a llamar mi función para subir el archivo, en donde están los astericos si meto una url directa si me crea el archivo, pero lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione un archivo se guarde la url para que se guarde el archivo

```
    `<?php
     include('ftp.php');
     uploadFTP("ave-la.dynns.com", "usuario", "acceso", "*****", "BLABLA/");
     ?>
      <form name="enviador" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" size="150" maxlength="150">
     Archivo: <input type="file" name="fichero">`
```

Esta es mi funcióncpara subir el archivo.

```
     <?php
function uploadFTP($server, $username, $password, $local_file, $remote_file){
// connect to server
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

// login
if (@ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)){
    // successfully connected
    echo "conectado";
}else{
     echo "no conectado";
    return false;
}

ftp_put($connection, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($connection);
return true;
```

}
?>

Comment: Hola Daniel, tu pregunta no es clara. Se supone que cuando vas a *poner* un archivo en el servidor ya sabes de antemano cómo se llamará y en qué carpeta irá. Si no se sabe, entonces explica por qué no se sabe, por qué se debe dejar al azar el nombre que debe tener ese archivo o por qué hay que conocerlo a posteriori. Si es así, **debes explicar el criterio de nombrado** que hay que seguir para *poner* el archivo en el servidor.

Comment: Hola que tal, si con enviar el archivo no tengo ningún problema, el detalle está en que necesito obtener la url de dónde proviene el archivo,si pongo está ruta "C:\Users\Asus.DESKTOP-JBDH3N9\Downloads" seguido del nombre del archivo que pretendo subir, pero quiero que se obtenga "x" ruta al momento de subir el archivo a través del form

Comment: Sigo si entender. El archivo no proviene de una URL sino de una ruta local en el cliente. No tiene sentido querer recuperar esa ruta local, porque la misma puede variar en todo momento. Por favor explica qué es lo que quieres porque no se entiende. Lo lógico es querer recuperar la ruta del archivo en el servidor, pero es un dato que deberías saber antes de guardar el archivo, al menos en este contexto.

Comment: Gracias amigo, te explicaré mi código,  uploadFTP("ave-la.dynns.com(Este es el nombre del servidor)", "usuario(Este es el usuario del servidor)", "acceso(Esta la contraseña)", "C:\Users\Asus.DESKTOP-JBDH3N9\Downloads(En esta linea si pongo la ruta especifica de donde proviene el archivo si me lo sube al servidor, lo que quiero es que cuando se seleccione el archivo ahí se ponga la ruta del archivo en automatico, no sé si lo que quiero hacer esta mal o me podrías orientar de como hacerlo)", "BLABLA/(Esta es la ruta en donde se va a guardar en el servidor)");

Comment: Es que no logro entender que es lo que quieres obtener en sí y para qué. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta, tratando de explicar con sencillez lo que quieres.